# Inserting NULL value for a string variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, null, dbnull

I'm trying to insert a NULL value to a variable of type string. Please let me know the possible ways to do it. I googled about this problem and found that DBNul.value can be assigned to the particular variable that has to be inserted as NULL. When i tried it errored out saying DB.Null cannot be converted to type `system.string`.

Comment: It would help to see what you have. It's not clear here whether you're trying to build an SQL command, or what you want the results to look like. There's clearly something else going on here. Otherwise, why not just `myStringVar = null;`?

Comment: I m trying to insert a null record to a column by SQL.     I have not tried myStringVar = null yet.

Comment: Please find the below snippet... i m using SqlCommand....i m reading the value of flag from a file and trying to insert into database....  i m unable to paste the whole code here...but below is the actual part where i m facing issue                                            Dim flag As String                                                                                                                                           if flag = ""                                                                         query = insert  into table (id, name, state, flag) values (1, xx, NY, NULL)

Comment: Please put your question information into your question and delete the comment. You can put UPDATE above it to show you have added it in addition to your original question.

Comment: **NEVER** use string concatenation to put values into SQL statements! That's a good way to find out a year later that your app was hacked six months ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a NULL value to a string in by setting it to nothing

```
dim MyString as string
MyString = nothing
```

A VBNull.Value is generally used to apply a null value when using a database insertion, or to verify if the recieved value is null.

**EDIT:** As you made clear you want to add a null value to a database, this can be achieved by setting the null value directly in the command object:

```
Dim Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand 'Use the proper database command
Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2) Values (@Value1, @Value2)"
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString1), DBNull.Value, MyString1))
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString2), DBNull.Value, MyString2))
```

Comment: This will insert a blank space into the database not a null value as the OP is requesting.

Comment: I could have probably misunderstood his question, but i think he is trying to apply a value to a variable, not to a database, isn't it?

Comment: If i use My string = nothing....just blank box appears against that column in Database which would affect if i query for NULL values for the column

Comment: AugustoQ...i m trying to insert into database

Comment: @Kals Edited the answer for a SQL insertion, please, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq to SQL or the similar Entity Framework, you can store DBNull using `Nothing`

I have a simple table with...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nchar](10) NULL,
```

and using this code...

```
Sub Main()
    Using dc As New DataClasses1DataContext
        Dim testNothing = New Table_1
        testNothing.Description = Nothing
        testNothing.TestID = 1
        dc.Table_1s.InsertOnSubmit(testNothing)
        Dim testEmpty = New Table_1
        testEmpty.Description = ""
        testEmpty.TestID = 2
        dc.Table_1s.InsertOnSubmit(testEmpty)
        dc.SubmitChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

the contents of the table is...

<kbd>ID</kbd>    <kbd>TestID</kbd><kbd>Description</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>NULL</kbd>         
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Nothing.

myStringVar = Nothing

Comment: That will not insert a null value. It will insert a blank value.